# How to create filename.tar.Z file on SunOS operatting system

Tags: unix, shell

I am trying to create `filename.tar.Z` file using single command on SunOS but it doesn’t seem to work:

```
bash-3.2$ tar c DIR | compress >DIR.tar.Z
tar: /dev/rmt/0: Permission denied
bash-3.2$
```

Other way I tried is like this:

```
bash-3.2$  tar cf DIR DIR.tar | compress -f DIR.tar
DIR.tar: No such file or directory
tar: DIR: Is a directory
```

I only want to create `filename.tar.Z` only no other compressed file. For example if I write command one after other it works like:

```
bash-3.2$ ls
DIR
bash-3.2$ tar -cf DIR.tar DIR
bash-3.2$ ls
DIR      DIR.tar
bash-3.2$ compress -f DIR.tar
bash-3.2$ ls
DIR        DIR.tar.Z
bash-3.2$
```

I don’t have edit rights for my post so please suggest something useful.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
tar cvf - DIR | compress -c >DIR.tar.Z
```

It works as follows:

- `tar` creates (`c`) an archive, and writes to the file `-` (`f`), which means standard output. That is now piped to `compress`, which also writes to the standard output (`-c`). We redirect that to a file.

Comment: Thanks its working from command prompt but from shell script it gives error . shell script has two input

Comment: first input =tar cvf - DIR                                                                                                                       second input=compress -c >DIR.tar.Z

Comment: shell script code :                                              a=$1                                                            b=$2                                                                      `$a|$b`

Comment: Error :Command failed with code 1                                          is something i am missing

Comment: I don't understand. Please post in your question the *complete* code of the script.